# Woocommerce checkout page "place order" button disabled

Tags: wordpress, checkout

I'm using cash on delivery service for my site running on loaclhost. If I update any section(pincode or address textbox) of my billing part or select checkbox "ship to differnt address" the place order button get's disabled. Even if i undo all the changes made to address or pincode the place order button becomes active just for a millisecond and then  again goes in  deactivated state. On reloading the page it again becomes active.

Comment: Sounds like an Ajax error, are the any errors logged in your browser console?

Comment: @M.Doye now it works just fine, all by itself. I have deacivated two plugins
1) woocommerce customizer 2) woo checkout field editor.